# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql

Не могу подключиться к локальному серверу MySQL через сокет `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` (2 "Нет такого файла или каталога")

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы подключаетесь по "localhost" или "127.0.0.1"?

При подключении "localhost" используется сокет, а при "127.0.0.1" - TCP/IP.

Попробуйте использовать "127.0.0.1", если сокет не работает.

Источник - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock

Также посмотрите там другие ответы, т.к. предлагается множество вариантов решения данной ошибки.